# Get data from a specific line in text file using BufferedReader

Tags: java, android, eclipse, text-files

I am currently building an application that is extracting values from a text file inside a project. Somehow managed extract data from specific lines but don't seem to get the right one.

Here is the code:

```
 private String getInputsFromATextFile(int item) throws FileNotFoundException {         
    InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.input);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    int lineNo = 0;
    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;            
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            lineNo++;
            if(lineNo == item){
                builder.append(reader.readLine());
            }

        }
        reader.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    return builder.toString();
}
```

And here are the text file contents:

```
20.45
21.65
1
225
4102
401
3
3
6
1
196.41
64.11
7
3
5
2
144.01
3
452.33
12
701.33
33
78.12
12
123.90
4
25.00
10
6.51
30.98
2.50
Spiderman
100.00
90
150.00
100
10
34
12
James
1267
Joshue
401
Christelle
3050
Ryan
888
Hanna
5
13
24
9
5
3
50
```

Suppose we assign a certain line number in a parameter. This method returns the exact next data from which the line number is assigned. Although, maybe I can adjust to the output that it always returns (lineNo + 1), but if in case I assigned '0' (zero) in the parameter, it instead returns null. Why is that so? I must be missing something really important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're reading the line again in the statement `builder.append(reader.readLine())`.
Notice that you've already read it in `while` loop.

So, the correct statement would be:
`builder.append(line);`

Comment: No problem! These kind of things happen all the time and we don't even notice them. Glad I could help =)

Answer (score 0):

Don't read it again when appending it. Use :

`builder.append(line);`

Also, if you want it to be `0` indexed, you should increment `lineno` after comparing it.

```
if(lineno == item)
{
}
lineno ++;
```

If you do it before comparision, it will never be `0` and hence returns a `null` .

---

**Is that optimal?**
If it just a one time retireval Yes.

If you use it again and again - No, everytime you want data from the line, you need to traverse the whole file till that line.

One way you can do is to store it in an ArrayList.

```
 InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.input);
 ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();
    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;            
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
           list.add(line);
        }
        reader.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
getLineFromFile(list, 10);
```

Store all the strings in an arrayList and then retrieve them.

```
public String getLineFromFile(ArrayList<String> list, int lineNo);
{
 return list.get(lineNo - 1);
}
```